# Stem and Leaf plot with outliers

Tags: tables

I would like to create this
[image]

I have this code so far

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{r|l@{\hspace{4 pt}}l@{\hspace{4 pt}}l@{\hspace{4 pt}}l@{\hspace{4 pt}}l@{\hspace{4 pt}}}
        \multicolumn{5}{l}{}\\ 
        LO  &12 &12\\ \hline
        4   &0\\
        5   &9\\
        6   &0\\
        7   &2 &5 &9 &9\\
        8   &4 &7\\
        9   &1 &4 &4 &5 &9\\
        10  &0 &1 &3 &9\\
        11  &1 &9 &9\\
        12  &7\\
        13  &1 &4\\
        14  &1\\ \hline
        HI  &172
    \end{tabular}
    \caption*{$ n=28\ 1|2 $ represents £1.20}
\end{table}
```

which then gives me

[image]

how can I get rid of the horizontal lines next to LO and HI and sort out the spacing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm just learning how to use latex

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) To get rid of the vertical line in the first and last row of your table, you can use `\multicolumn{1}{r}{LO}` and `\multicolumn{1}{r}{HI}`. What exactly does "sort out the spacing"  refer to here?

Comment: Great thank you for that I'll give it a go and by sort out the spacing I'd rather have the LO and HI numbers not affect the spacing of the columns within the rest of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{r|l@{\hspace{4 pt}}l@{\hspace{4 pt}}l@{\hspace{4 pt}}l@{\hspace{4 pt}}l@{\hspace{4 pt}}}
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{LO}  &\rlap{12 12}\\ \hline
        4   &0\\
        5   &9\\
        6   &0\\
        7   &2 &5 &9 &9\\
        8   &4 &7\\
        9   &1 &4 &4 &5 &9\\
        10  &0 &1 &3 &9\\
        11  &1 &9 &9\\
        12  &7\\
        13  &1 &4\\
        14  &1\\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{HI}  &\rlap{172}
    \end{tabular}
    \caption*{$ n=28\ 1|2 $ represents £1.20}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: That is exactly what I needed thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

What about the following?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
    \begin{tabular}{rr|llllll}
        & \multicolumn{5}{l}{}\\ 
        & \multicolumn{1}{r}{LO}  & \multicolumn{5}{l}{12 \hspace{\tabcolsep} 12} \\ \cline{2-7}
        & 4   &0\\
        & 5   &9\\
        & 6   &0\\
        & 7   &2 &5 &9 &9\\
        & 8   &4 &7\\
        & 9   &1 &4 &4 &5 &9\\
        & 10  &0 &1 &3 &9\\
        & 11  &1 &9 &9\\
        & 12  &7\\
        & 13  &1 &4\\
        & 14  &1\\ \cline{2-7}
        & \multicolumn{1}{r}{HI}  & \multicolumn{6}{l}{172} \\[0.25cm]
        \multicolumn{2}{r|}{n=28 1} & \multicolumn{6}{l}{2  represents £1.20}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```